# Background PHP script being terminated by Heroku

Tags: php, heroku

I have a background PHP script running on Heroku (using a worker dyno). I have overridden PHP time limits as the script needs plenty of time to run (it is systematically calling an API and storing results in MySQL).

Running on localhost, the script completes without problems. However, on Heroku it terminates after about 15 minutes. My log shows the following:

```
Jul 19 17:05:20 heroku heroku/run.4487: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes 
Jul 19 17:05:21 heroku heroku/run.4487: State changed from up to complete 
Jul 19 17:05:21 heroku heroku/run.4487: Process exited with status 129
```

What does this mean and how can I work around it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question to Heroku support and they told me it was because I was running the job from a command line, but the connection to the client was being lost.

The fix, for the benefit of anyone who might stumble upon this, is to replace `run` with `run:detached` in the command line. This detaches the job from me entirely and sets it free to run off into the sunset on its own.